# Can't deploy Django on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a project called "django_project" on local host tested & running.
Now i have tried deploying my app at Heroku (really tried everything) but there's error saying:

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn django_projcet.wsgi  
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed  
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3   
app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_projcet'      
app[web.1]: [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)     
app[web.1]: [INFO] Shutting down: Master      
app[web.1]: [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

My project tree:
[image]

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn django_projcet.wsgi
```

Wsgi.py:

```
"""
WSGI config for django_project project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_project.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

requirements.txt:

```
boto3==1.12.31
botocore==1.15.31
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.4
django-crispy-forms==1.9.0
django-storages==1.9.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
docutils==0.15.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.8
jmespath==0.9.5
Pillow==7.0.0
psycopg2==2.7.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
s3transfer==0.3.3
six==1.14.0
urllib3==1.25.8
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

To deploy django app in Heroku you need 3 files

1. runtime.txt
2. Procfile
3. requirements.txt

In runtime.txt mention your python version

```
python-3.7.8
```

In Procfile

```
web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi
```

For requirements.txt, You could use

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

> There is a mistake in your Procfile, You wrote **`web: gunicorn django_projcet.wsgi`**
>
> Change to **`web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi`**
>
> your project name does not match as in Procfile

Comment: You wrote the same procfile config as i wrote.. it's not working

Comment: @Moshe Kindly check your project name in Procfile, It's wrong